# Como inserir registros com PDO no MySQL sequencialmente

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou enviando seis campos de um formulário para inserir em meu MySQL mas somente os três primeiros estão indo corretamente, preciso inserir os três primeiros e na sequência os outros três, mas estou com essa dificuldade em entender como fazer.

As variáveis são essas?

```
$IdCandidato = $_SESSION['IdCandidato'];
$IdArea1 = $_POST['Area1'];
$IdCargo1 = $_POST['Cargo1'];
$Experiencia1 = $_POST['Experiencia1'];

$Area2 = $_POST['Area2'];
$Cargo2 = $_POST['Cargo2'];
$Experiencia2 = $_POST['Experiencia2'];

$DataHoraAtualizacao = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

As variáveis `IdCandidato` e `DataHoraAtualizacao` estou recuperando no momento da tentativa de gravação.

Vou colocar uma imagem para explicar melhor, o formulário é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A estrutura da tabela está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `crrAreaExpectativa` (
    `IdAreaExpectativa` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Código da area expectativa',
    `IdCandidato` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código do candidato',
    `Opcao` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Opção: 1 ou 2',
    `IdArea` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código da área',
    `IdCargo` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código do cargo',
    `DataHoraAtualizacao` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Data/Hora da atualização',
    PRIMARY KEY (`IdAreaExpectativa`, `IdCandidato`),
    INDEX `IDXOpcao` (`Opcao`),
    INDEX `IDXIdArea` (`IdArea`),
    INDEX `IDXIdCargo` (`IdCargo`),
    INDEX `FK_AreaExpectativa_Candidato` (`IdCandidato`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_AreaExpectativa_Candidato` FOREIGN KEY (`IdCandidato`) REFERENCES `crrCandidato` (`IdCandidato`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COMMENT='Área e cargo onde o candidato deseja trabalhar'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=14
;
```

O que estou tentando fazer é isso:

```
try {

    // INICIALIZA A TRANSAÇÃO
    $conexao->beginTransaction();

        try {                

            // INSERT 3 PRIMEIROS CAMPOS
            $sql1 = 'INSERT INTO `crrAreaExpectativa` (`IdCandidato`, `Opcao`, `IdArea`, `IdCargo`, `DataHoraAtualizacao`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql1);
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdCandidato, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $Experiencia1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(3, $IdArea1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(4, $IdCargo1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(5, $DataHoraAtualizacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $retorno = $stm->execute(); 


            // INSERT 3 ÚLTIMOS CAMPOS
            $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO `crrAreaExpectativa` (`IdCandidato`, `Opcao`, `IdArea`, `IdCargo`, `DataHoraAtualizacao`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql2);
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdCandidato, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $Experiencia2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(3, $IdArea2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(4, $IdCargo2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(5, $DataHoraAtualizacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $retorno = $stm->execute(); 

            $conexao->commit();

        } catch (PDOException $erro) {  

                // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
                $conexao->rollBack();           
                $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao inserir o registro. Tente novamente [2]. ::$erro');
                $conexao = null;        

                // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
                echo json_encode($retorno);
                exit();             

        }



} catch (Exception $e) {    

    // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
    $conexao->rollBack();   
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Ocorreu um erro na gravação, tente novamente [5]. ::$erro');              
    $conexao = null;        

    // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();     
}

$retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Registro inserido com sucesso');  

// FECHA CONEXÃO
$conexao = null;        

// RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As variáveis não estão iguais. Na parte onde você recebe os valores dos 3 últimos campos por `$_POST` está com o nome errado em relação ao seu insert no banco.

Como está:

```
$Area2 = $_POST['Area2'];
$Cargo2 = $_POST['Cargo2'];
```

Como deveria está:

```
$IdArea2 = $_POST['Area2'];
$IdCargo2 = $_POST['Cargo2'];
```

Assim, as variáveis ficaram iguais ás variáveis do seu insert:

```
$stm->bindValue(3, $IdArea2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(4, $IdCargo2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Caramba o tal do teste viciado me pegou de verdade, obrigado @TalesPeres pela grande ajuda e olhar apurado, valeu.